# how can we replace '\' from a string in php.

Tags: php

I tried str_replace and also preg_replace by writing it as a '\' but both are not worked

```
  $old[0]= '\item'
  $new='';
  $fread = str_replace($old, $new, $fread);
```

It only remove 'item' from the string.

```
$fread=preg_replace('/\\item/', "", $fread);
```

It also remove only 'item' from $fread.

Comment: What is your `$fread` ?

Comment: you are using wrong quote use double quote

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$fread = 'is this "\item" gone yet?';

$old = '\\item'; //OR  [ 'item', '\\'];

$new='';

echo str_replace($old, $new, $fread) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  $fread = 'is this \item gone yet? \"hmmm\". it\'s a ball.';
  $search= ["\\", "item"]; // use double quote for backslash and escape with backslash
  $replace=['', ''];
  $fread = str_replace($search, $replace, $fread);
  echo $fread; // is this  gone yet? "hmmm". it's a ball.
```